# SSIS linked to a mySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

in SQL server it's possible to link a mySQL server into msSQL and query it using SSMS for example. I want to try this and use SSIS to do some transformations and store all the data on this mySQL database.

\I read that there a several ways to link to mySQL into the msSQL server. OLE DB, mySQL ODBC etc etc.

2 questions:

Are there any limitations i might run into when i will use a combination of SSIS and mySQL instead of msSQL?

When i link a mySQL database into msSQL and i write a query in SSMS, do i write the queries in mySQL language or msSQL language. For example the difference in TOP and LIMIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked with a linked MySQL Server from SQL Server in the past and ran into some issues.

**Querying MySQL from SSMS (SQL Server)**

Once you have created a linked server you would imagine you should be able to use the four-part name and query the tables in MySQL but it doesnt allow you. for example you cannot do something like...

```
Select * from MySqlServer.DbName.Schema.TableName
```

For some reason it throws an error. So the question whether I can use T-SQL in SSMS to query a Linked MySQL Server? Nope, unfortunately not.

But alternatively Microsoft recommends using `OPENQUERY` to execute queries to a linked server.

When using OPENQUERY, SQL Server does not try to parse the query, it just sends it to the linked server as it is. which means you can/should be able to write `MySQL` in `SSMS` using `OPENQUERY` and it will work.

**Using SSIS with MySQL**

Even though `SSIS` is Microsoft's tool that comes with `SQL Server` but it is a proper `ETL` tool which can read data from multiple sources and send data to many types of destination.

Once you have used the appropriate driver to connect to `MySQL` and ported data in `SSIS` package , its really not relevant anymore, where the data came from? you would have access to all the `SSIS` tools and you should be able to use them as if the data was coming from a flat file, SQL Server or Excel sheet etc.

Answer (score 0):

By using **Linked Server** in MSSQL you can also connect to **mySql**. for that you need to **download ODBC drivers**. and then you have to create new dsn and while creating dsn you have to insert mySql server's details. then you can further search regarding how to create Linked server on SQL SERVER. This option is very easy and Totally free. You can use OPEN QUERY FOR inserting, updating, deleting and also get the data out from mySQL.

Comment: Linked server is the easiest method to use and you can do it very easily by following steps.